# Jekyll - Include multiple parameters in single include?

Tags: jekyll

Is it possible to include multiple parameters in single include?

Single:

{% include card.html class=include.class1 %}

Multiple??

{% include card.html class=include.class1 && include.class2 %}

Or do I have to do class1=include.class1 class2=include.class2?

Answer (score 6):

Multiple [include](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/) parameters can be passed separated with a space `param1=value1 param2=value2`,e.g.:

```
{% include image.html url="http://jekyllrb.com"
max-width="200px" file="logo.png" alt="Jekyll logo"
caption="This is the Jekyll logo." %}
```

Then you can access them *inside* the include file prefixing it with `include.`, for example:

```
{{include.file}} {{include.caption}}
```

Comment: Hey Marc! Thanks. Yes I've got that working fine, its more that I want to pass multiple values into a single paramater. For example{% include card.html class=include.class1 && include.class2 %}

Comment: @Rhys  so you can create an array or concatenate those parameters in a string and then pass them as a single value, then deconstruct it inside the include, I don't understand why would you need this though

Comment: No worries thanks. The only case where I have wanted it would be to pass multiple classes into a component. For example, a modifier and disabled class.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, was able to use capture to achieve this. @marcanuy

Comment: @Rhys Nice! Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @marcanuy,

One way is to use the capture function to include multiple values into a single parameter.

{% capture classes %} {{include.class1}}  {{include.class2}} {% endcapture %}

{% include card.html class=classes %}

Answer (score 0):

Here's my use case for this-

an include that has html for a radiobutton set, like so:

```
<label>{{include.label}}</label> 
{% for option in include.options %}
<input type="radio" name="{{include.label}}" id="{{include.option}}" value="{{include.option}}" checked="checked"/><label for="  {{include.option}}">{{include.option}}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

that you call like this:

```
{% include radiobuttons.html label="favorite color" options="green", "blue", "orange", "red" %}
```